# Unity - InvalidCastException on Editor auto-refresh for List of object (who was valid before)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, casting

I'm working on a project manager who define scripts who can be used by multiple of others project later (by extending some part to update them).

I actually have:

- 2 namespaces **Foo** (the manager) and **Bar** (the project)
- Both define an object **Character** (Bar.Character extend from Foo.Character)
- FooEngine is here to list Foo.Character (List)
- FooEngineEditor (defined on Bar namespace) is here in order to add (both Foo or Bar Character) and display Characters (and their cast)

### Foo

```
namespace Foo
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Character
    {
        public int ID;
        public Character(int ID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    }


    public class FooEngine : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<Foo.Character> list = new List<Foo.Character>();
    }
}
```

### Bar

```
namespace Bar
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Character: Foo.Character
    {
        public string name;
        public MyObject(int ID, string name)
            : base (ID) {
            this.name= name;
        }
    }

    [CustomEditor(typeof(Foo.FooEngine))]
    public class FooEngineEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            Foo.FooEngine fooEngine = (Foo.FooEngine)target;

            // --- Default inspector
            DrawDefaultInspector();

            // --- Action

            int countExistig = fooEngine.list.Count;

            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Add Foo.Character"))
            {
                fooEngine.list.Add(new Foo.Character(countExistig));
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Add Bar"))
            {
                fooEngine.list.Add(new Bar.Character(countExistig, "abc"));
            }

            // --- Review
            for (int i = 0, l = fooEngine.list.Count; i < l; i++)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField(" - " + i + " > " + fooEngine.list.GetType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everyting is working fine and I can use the Editor script in order to Add Foo.Character or Bar.Character into the same list (and casting works fine).

But when I save code, List are re-casted into Foo.Character and will create InvalidCastException Error if I try to cast `Bar.Character character = (Bar.Character)fooEngine.list[0];`

[image]

What's append and what's causing the list to be recasted ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C# concept issue. You cannot cast an object created as an instance of a base class to a derived class. That's not how polymorphism is designed. If you create an object as a Foo.Character, it can never be cast to a Bar.Character which inherits it UNLESS that object was created as a Bar.Character originally, then cast to a base object, and then back again.

The idea of a base class, which appears to be your use case of the  Foo.Character class, is to be a common class that several derive from, and not a class that you instantiate (abstract class, for example). I would enforce that one cannot create a Foo.Character, given this scenario. And therefore all instances must be a Bar.Character or any other derived instance of the base character.

Simply changing this line

```
Bar.Character character = (Bar.Character)fooEngine.list[0];
```

to

```
Foo.Character character = (Foo.Character)fooEngine.list[0];
```

Will compile and execute given your example. It will cast everything to its base class, but you will still have data from the original Bar.Character before casting (This will only work in your example, but not my suggested code below).

Here are my suggested changes:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo.FooEngine fooEngine = new Foo.FooEngine();
            //TODO: NO LONGER POSSIBLE fooEngine.list.Add(new Foo.Character(0));
            fooEngine.list.Add(new Bar.Character(0, "Test1"));
            fooEngine.list.Add(new Example.Character(0, "Test2"));
            Bar.Character character = (Bar.Character)fooEngine.list[0];
            Example.Character character2 = (Example.Character)fooEngine.list[1];

        }
    }
}

namespace Foo
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public abstract class Character
    {
        public int ID;
    }


    public class FooEngine
    {
        public List<Foo.Character> list = new List<Foo.Character>();
    }
}

namespace Bar
{

    public class Character : Foo.Character
    {
        public string name;
        public Character(int ID, string name)
        {
            base.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}

namespace Example
{

    public class Character : Foo.Character
    {
        public string name;
        public Character(int ID, string name)
        {
            base.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```